# How to specify LOD bias in Metal?

Tags: ios, meta, cifilter

I'm rewriting an OpenGL filter from the Android version of the app I'm currently working at in Metal. It uses the following texture lookup function:
`vec4 texture2D(sampler2D sampler, vec2 coord, float bias)`

Assuming my filter kernel function looks like this:

```
float4 fname(sampler src) {
    ...
}
```

The texture lookup call would be the following:

```
src.sample(coord)
```

But how can I pass the bias parameter? (the sample function takes only 1 argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid Core Image only supports 2D textures – no mipmapping and LOD selection. Only bilinear sampling is available.

If you need different LODs, you need to pass different samplers to your kernel and do the interpolation yourself.